# Comprobar un campo de la base de datos con keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando consultar un campo de la base de datos con jQuery y Keyup. El problema que esto comprueba si un email existe, al estar editando un usuario ya tiene un email, si pone el mismo que ya tiene en la BD no me puede arrojar que ya existe ese email. Entonces estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Primero obtengo el usuario que estoy editando un keyup:

```
$usuarioQueEdito = Cliente::where('id', '=', $request->id)->first();
```

Luego realizo lo siguiente:

```
if($request->search = $usuarioQueEdito->email){
   $html = "<div class=\"codigoNoExiste\"><i class=\"fas fa-times-circle\"></i>Este email ya es del usuario actual</div>";
}else{
   $user = Cliente::where('email', '=', $request->search)->first();
     if ($user === null) {
       $html = "<div class=\"codigoExiste\"><i class=\"fas fa-check-circle\"></i> Perfecto! Este cliente no existe</div>";
     }else{
       $html = "<div class=\"codigoNoExiste\"><i class=\"fas fa-times-circle\"></i> Este cliente ya existe, prueba con otro</div>";
     }
}
return $html;
```

En mi cabeza suena bien, obtengo el usuario que estoy recibiendo a través de keyup con `$request->id`, una vez lo obtengo pregunto, `$request->search = $usuarioQueEdito->email` "si el mail que recibo a través de keyup es igual al de `$usuarioQueEdito` muestra que es el actual, si no es así, realizo una consulta para que compruebe si ese email existe en la base de datos, si no existe le digo Perfecto y por lo contrario le digo que ya existe.

Pero todo el rato me devuelve: `Este email ya es del usuario actual` que estoy haciendo mal???

Comment: Podrías ahorrarte una consulta si filtras por correo e id diferente del usuario en sesión, quizá algo como: `$user = Cliente::where('email', $request->search)->where('id', '!=', $request->id)->first();`

Comment: Hola @Triby gracias por tu respuesta, todo lo que sea ahorrarse código y este más limpio mejor, pero que tendría que eliminar la segunda consulta?

Comment: Voy a agregar otra respuesta para decirte cómo simplificar, pero deja marcada la que ya está, porque solucionó tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu error esta en la primera condición

```
if($request->search = $usuarioQueEdito->email)
```

Le estás asignando un valor a `$request->search` y no comparándolo. Debería ser así

```
if($request->search == $usuarioQueEdito->email)
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchas gracias @Henry marca zeballos !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas una consulta para verificar que el correo no está siendo usado en otro registro. Si se trata del usuario actual, entonces no habrá problema, porque no se va a duplicar:

```
$user = Cliente::where('email', $request->search) // ¿Existe el correo en tabla?
    ->where('id', '!=', $request->id) // No debe buscar en ID actual
    ->first();
if ($user === null) {
    $html = "<div class=\"codigoExiste\"><i class=\"fas fa-check-circle\"></i> ¡Perfecto! Este correo está disponible</div>";
}else{
    $html = "<div class=\"codigoNoExiste\"><i class=\"fas fa-times-circle\"></i> Ya hay un usuario registrado usando este correo, intenta con otro</div>";
}
return $html;
```

Con esto evitas una consulta innecesaria y simplificas los mensajes a mostrar.

Comment: Pero así no te llegaría el mensaje de que el correo que has puesto ya es el del usuario actual, osea es decir, lo que tu ya estas haciendo es descartar el que tiene este usuario, pero debería de mostrar algo? lo ves necesario?

Comment: @Miguel, si se trata de verificar disponibilidad para usar un correo, esto es suficiente, así es como lo manejo en mis proyectos. Si te interesa saber si pertenece al mismo usuario, entonces continúa con tu script original, eso ya depende de ti.

Comment: No para nada, lo he probado y mi parece mucho mejor así, muchas gracias como siempre @Triby

Comment: @Miguel, me disculpo si mi comentario anterior sonó mal, solo estaba mencionando las dos opciones y que eres tú quien debe decidir cuál es la mejor, de acuerdo a tu proyecto.

Comment: Para nada sonó mal :) pero tienes razón en tu comentario. Sigo siendo muy novato en programación y por eso me gusta pedir consejo para aprender de los que más saben. De verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda y el consejo!